# Is my thinking about OOP persistence-separation right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop

I am reading about OOP and trying to apply it to Rails (inspired by Uncle Bob's Ruby conf talk), and I was wondering, is it right to access the repository from a "logic" model in the way I do below:

```
class Product
  ...
  def pick_a_random_product
    repository.pick_a_random_product
  end
  ...
end
```

Does this qualify as "logic being separated from persistence" ? Is it O.K to be using the `repository` as extensively as may be needed, inside a "domain"/"logic" model?

`repository` is meant to be some class that does the real job of fetching something from the database.

Comment: I thought Rails is all about ActiveRecord.

Comment: Sort of. And I am trying to break away from the "Rails Way". Because of Ruby, and some great things about Rails, I really want to stay with them but still use OOP in the way it is meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

It works but if pick_a_random_product is use for different class means that

Suppose you have class xyz

```
Class Xyz
  ...
  def pick_a_random_product
    Product.pick_a_random_product
    # Xyz.pick_a_random_product you can't use this.
  end
  ...
end
```

you have class Product

```
class Product
  ...
  def pick_a_random_product
    Xyz.pick_a_random_product
  end
  ...
end
```